# Populate ref field in mongo (using mongoose) to a different path

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a model object that looks like this:

```
   OrderSchema = new Schema({
        order_id: {type: String, unique: true},
        customer: {
            address:addressModel,
            first_name : {type:String, default:''},
            last_name : {type:String, default:''},
            company : {type:String, default:''},
            phone1 : phoneModel,
            phone2 : phoneModel,
            email : {type:String},
            mask : {type:Boolean, default:false},
        },
        retailer: {
            _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Retailer' }
        }
    }
```

and retailer looks like this:

```
RetailerSchema = new Schema({
    company: {type:String, required: true},
    identifier: {type:String, required: true, unique: true},
    first_name: {type:String},
    last_name: {type:String},
    address: addressModel,
    phone1:phoneModel,
    phone2:phoneModel
})
```

when i use the `.populate` mongoose function, the resulted object looks somewhat like this:

```
queryCall.populate('retailer._id','company address')
```

...

```
 "retailer": {
        "_id": {
            "address": {
                "address1": "51 Astor Place",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "New York",
                "state": "NY",
                "zip": "10003"
            },
            "_id": "5d4482a35555d200208b3cd4",
            "company": "123"
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to create a map, which after i populate the resulted object would be just an extension of the field that is populated, hence, something like below. I'm trying pretty much to see if there is a way to populate the result to a different path on the resulted object.

```
   "retailer": {
        "_id": "5d4482a35555d200208b3cd4",
        "address": {
                "address1": "51 Astor Place",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "New York",
                "state": "NY",
                "zip": "10003"
            }
        },
        "company": "123"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `retailer` field from the `OrderSchema` schema to:

```
retailer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Retailer' }
```

and call `.populate` like this:

```
queryCall.populate('retailer', 'company address')
```

If you cannot edit the schema then you could use an aggregation as follows:

```
OrderSchema.aggregate([/* { $match: { // put your conditions here }  } */])
  .lookup({ from: 'retailers', localField: 'retailer._id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'retailer' })
  .unwind('retailer')
  .project({
    // other fields,
    retailer: {
      address: 1,
      company: 1
    }
  })
```

Or if you want to use only javascript:

```
return orders.map(order => (order.retailer = order.retailer._id, order));
```

Comment: the issue is that my database is already structured like this, is there any other way to orchestrate it?